# PetitFS Streaming Read

Tags: arduino, streaming, spi

Propably a pretty stupid/simple question:
I'm using the arduino wrapper of Petit FS and I'm trying to do a streaming read of data into a FIFO.

The Library says it supports streaming read and I need to pass buffer=NULL to activate it but I can't figure out which method I need to implement/Rewrite/Overrite to handle my data while reading/streaming

Can anyone help me out?

Never mind, in the avr_mmcp file, is a constant defining a function which is used as streaming function. No idea how I missed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the avr_mmcp file, is a constant defining a function which is used as streaming function.